# Adding actors/musicians/famous people in a videogame

Tags: legal

Let's say I want to make a videogame with several famous characters in it, you can't copyright a name and a face, right (I'm talking about names and surnames, not branded ones)? How does it work? Are there any royalties to pay? To whom? If there are royalties, can I get away by making my names similar to original ones?

Comment: Depending on where you are there are different laws which govern personality rights on the one side and freedom of speech regarding celebrities on the other. This is more of a question for https://law.stackexchange.com